# How to set the order elements are appended to a documentFragment when being returned async?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, appendchild, rsvp.js

Odd question I guess...

I'm building my DOM in memory and make heavy use of `promises`. Say I have this inside a `for...` loop:

```
target = document.createDocumentFragment();
promises = [], pass, skip, store;

for (i = 0; i < foo; i += 1) {
    element = foo[i];

    // set promise
    promises[i] = app.setContent(element, {}, update)
        .then(function(response) {
            // HELP!
            if (pass) {
              target.appendChild(store)
              store = undefined;
              skip = undefined;
              pass = undefined;
            }
            if (response.tagName !== undefined) {
              pass = true;
            }
            if (skip === undefined && response.tagName === undefined) {
              store = response;
              skip = true;
            } else {
              target.appendChild(response);
            }
          });

  RSVP.all(promises).then(continue...
```

The loop above runs `3x` returning two `div` tags and a `documentFragment`. Without promises, no problem, my structure is

```
 <div toolbar>
 <fragment = form>
 <div toolbar>
```

Problem is, when I converted to `async` I have no more say in the order items get appended forcing me to stupid things as above, where I'm finding my fragment, store it in `store`, set a `skip` parameter, append my first div, which sets `pass`, which will allow my stored `fragment` to be appended when the next promises "comes in"... what a waste of code...

**Question**:
Is there any way to properly set the order of items in a **generic** way when all items are being returned async? If not, how do I move items? Since I'm working in memory, I can select using `querySelector/qsAll` but I don't have a lot of other options? Any ideas?

(And please don't suggest to put in the DOM and then shuffle :-))

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll explain in words ...

On making each async request, also create a container, in the right place, for the requested data to go when it eventually arrives. This container will typically be a `<div>` or a `<span>`.

Keep a reference to the container (typically in a closure) such that the async response handler knows which container corresponds to which data.

Comment: Workday ended. Happy to not see my code for a few hours... Will let you know tomorrow.

Comment: I know where you're coming from.

Comment: You can probably stick the containers (`<tr>s`?) straight into the DOM, and cut out the middle-man - the fragment. With a little more thought, you could have the containers display "loading...", to be replaced with the actual content when it arrives.

Comment: I gave up on the table but the random cell shuffle sure looks funny. Btw - I'm building everything in memory, so no DOM touches. So I need fragments because fragment and qsa work in memory :-)